# Извлечь ссылку на изображение с сайта с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, jsoup, парсер

Есть код на одном вебсайте:

```
<script>
"img":["ссылка на изображение","ссылка на изображение2","ссылка на изображение3","ссылка на изображение4"]
</script>
```

Мой код, что бы достать  ссылки изображения:

```
 Elements scripts = doc.select("script");

  for (Element script : scripts) {
        String scriptText = script.html();

        if (scriptText.contains("\"img\"")) {
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(scriptText)) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    if (line.contains("\"img\"")) {
                        String link = line.split("img:[\"")[1]
                                .split("]")[0];
                        String extension = link.substring(
                                link.length() - 3, link.length());

                        images.add(new Image(link ,
                                referrer, extension));
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Что вы получаете на выходе? Какой класс/либу используете для парсинга? Другие элементы разметки парсятся?

Comment: Мне кажется, что  не получается получить каждую ссылку отдельно.

Comment: Таки что выводит то код ваш? И вы явно неверно подходите к решению проблемы. Парсить HTML регулярками - то ещё извращение. Используйте любую либу которая может это делать легко и изящно.

Comment: Я пользуюсь  Jsoup.

Comment: Просто, не могу правильно переобразовать строку, в отдельные ссылки.

Comment: @RoseVinnur хорошо бы дополнить вопрос той информацией, которая возникла уже здесь, в комментариях. Напишите пожалуйста _перед_ "Что я делаю не так?", то что вы ожидаете получить от работы кода. И, как посоветовал Юрий, дополните пожалуйста заголовок. Сделайте его более информативным.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вы не разделили множество ссылок на части после

```
String link = line.split("img:[\"")[1]
                            .split("]")[0];
```

Теперь link должно содержать

> ссылка на изображение","ссылка на изображение2","ссылка на изображение3","ссылка на изображение4"

Вам надо изменить нынешний и добавить следующий код:

```
String link = line.split("img:[")[1]
                            .split("]")[0];
//уберём кавычки
link = link.replace("\"", ""); 
//порежем строку на массив. Разделяя по запятой.
String[] links = link.split(",");
```

**И самое главное** - не используйте регулярки для этого. Используйте библиотеки для парсинга HTML.

---

**P.S.** Сайт сей целью имеет **формирование базы данных вопросов о программировании**. Заголовок вашего вопроса для сих целей не подходит. Переформулируйте его.

Comment: Пример исчерпывающего ответа. ^